# Vb.net Input box Function

Tags: vb.net

Am using An inputbox in my form.

If i Press OK the code is fine.
When i Press cancel the Program displayin an error. Wat should i Do ?

Comment: please explain with code

Comment: What you should do is refine your question and be alot more specific. Maybe you should even attached code examples of what you are trying to do.

Comment: This question is not answerable in this state. Please clarify it

Comment: @anishmarokey @Younes @samy I agree the question would be a whole lot better with some example code, but in fact [InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx) is so simple that the question **can** be answered in its current state. Also, of course, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx) explains the behaviour on pressing cancel - it's very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code that is after the `InputBox` to support empty strings. `InputBox` will return an empty string if you cancel so the reason for the error must be that your code expects the string to have a lenght > 0.

If you edit the question to show the code that calls `InputBox` as well as a few lines following that line, someone can probably point out the exact error.

Answer (score 3):

You should look for an empty string

```
    Dim MyString As String

    MyString = InputBox("Please enter something", "Request Info", Nothing)
    If (MyString Is Nothing OrElse MyString = "") Then
        'User hit cancel
    Else
        'Read MyString
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for a working sample:

> **[`Interaction.InputBox` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx)**